# What does !!:2 mean in Bash?

Tags: bash

I was watching the [this](https://vimeo.com/56166857) video tutorial and around the 1:40 mark the author issues the following command. It creates two files, under the recently created folder.

```
touch !!:2/{package.json,index.js}
```

Can someone please explain what `!!:2` means? and why it didn't create the two files under all the folders?

Comment: BTW, this won't always work; specifically, it'll only work at all if `[[ $- = *H* ]]` evaluates to true (meaning history expansion is enabled). History expansion is turned off by default for scripts, and many interactive users (myself included) prefer to turn it off as well (since it makes commands that would work correctly in a script sometimes fail interactively if they contain components that can be interpreted as history expansion directives).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in bash you can use `!!` to repeat the previous command line. A typical usage is:

```
do some command that needs root permissions
# this fails, so:
sudo !!
```

which will expand to:

```
sudo do some command that needs root permissions
```

the expression `!!:2` means: *take the **third** (0-based indexing) word from the previous command line*.

example to illustrate:

```
$ echo these are some words in a sentence
these are some words in a sentence
$ echo !!:2
echo are
are
```

**NOTE** that this is extremely error prone, especially with the 0-based indexing

Comment: So the essence of good advice is to **not** use it if you had a coffee break, or gone to toilet, or had some other interruption and are not **absolutely** sure what your second to last issued command really was.

Comment: Shortcuts like this one are good for interactive usage, but should be avoided in scripts, documents and tutorials (else most people will have to stop reading and ask in stackoverflow)

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn, such shortcuts don't even **work** in scripts by default; history expansion is only turned on out-of-the-box for interactive shells.

Comment: And some companies force you to use at least one symbol (other than letters or digits) to use in your password, to consider it *safe* (har, har, har). Typing such a password containing "!" accidentally as shell command can have really surprising and unwanted effects.

Comment: I was really confused about the `:2` part. Thank you for the great explanation.

Comment: I corrected my answer; the indexing happens from the start of the command, not from the end as in my answer before. I adapted my example  so that the word 'are' isn't in the middle of the sentence...